# UIPickerView with a custom UITextField option

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

not sure if this is a rookie question as I this is my first time using the UIPickerView.

My UIPickerView in my class has this array:

```
let cameraBodies = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                    "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
                    "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","Other"]
```

When the user clicks on my textField they have a choice of the above strings. If the user chooses "other", I want the UIPickerView to dismiss and change to a normal TextField so the user can input their own string. And then if the user deletes all the custom text in the textField it would return to the UIPickerView.

I thought about having 2 textfields on top of each other that I would show/hide depending on what the user chooses but I feel like this wouldnt be the correct way to approach this.

Any help on how to achieve this would be great.

Here is a section of my class that has everything to do with the UIPickerView:

```
class newCameraController : UIViewController{

    var selectedBody: String?

    var cameraBodyCustomTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Custom Camera Body"
        return textField

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createBodyPicker()
        createToolBar()
    }

    func createBodyPicker() {

        let bodyPicker = UIPickerView()
        bodyPicker.delegate = self
        cameraBodyTextField.inputView = bodyPicker
    }

    func createToolBar() {

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(newCameraController.dismissKeyboard))

        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cameraBodyTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    override func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

extension newCameraController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return cameraBodies.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return cameraBodies[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        selectedBody = cameraBodies[row]
        cameraBodyTextField.text = selectedBody
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        var label: UILabel

        if let view = view as? UILabel {
            label = view
        } else {
            label = UILabel()
        }

        label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 16.0)

        label.text = cameraBodies[row]

        return label
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just check if the picked option is "Other" and then set the `textField.inputView = nil`. The problem would be going back. Consider scenario: "User chooses 'Other', textfield turns to just textfield, but user now wants to pick one of the options in the picker". It happens all the time. You should have a textfield hidden and only unhide it when "Other" is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my opinion, the solution is:
In your code, you are showing picker in place of a keyboard, it's correct.
Now when a user selects "Other", simply show selected value "Other" in cameraBodyTextField.
And show one extra text field just below cameraBodyTextField.
Show/Hide can be managed by autolayout hight constraints with smoother animation.

Comment: I did also consider this however, I am writing to CoreData and at the moment I am writing that textField to my entity and I didn't want to start making extra attributes in my entity that sometimes might be empty if the user chooses a letter. I am also referencing this attribute in other classes so that could also get quite confusing. Ideally, I would have it in one textField if possible?

Comment: @spoax
You can do conditional code. When user select other, consider otherTextField value, to input in database.
When in edit mode, try to find same value in datasource (array of string), for set default selected row of picker view. If found, hide "OtherTextField". If not found, set "Other" in pickerview and, show otherTextField with database value.
Using this approach will make less confusion to user experience.